# Angular test combineLatest with Jest

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, observable, combinelatest

I'm stuck with a test with a more complicated Statement towards combineLatest. It looks like this:

**component:**

```
export class ErinnerungenErinnerungenComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {    

...

erinnerungen: ErinnerungModel[] = [];

ErinnerungData$ = combineLatest([
this.featureSessionStoreService.auftragIdLookupModelSubject,
this.updateGridSubject]).pipe
(
  tap(() => this.loadingGridSubject.next(true)),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.erinnerungService.getErinnerungenForAuftrag(
      this.featureSessionStoreService.auftragIdLookupModel as GetErinnerungenForAuftrag
    )
  ),
  tap((erinnerungenModel) => {
    this.erinnerungen = erinnerungenModel.erinnerungen;
  }),
  tap(() => this.loadingGridSubject.next(false)),
  takeUntil(this.componentIsDestroyed$)
  )
.subscribe();


constructor(...) {}

ngOnInit() {...}

}
```

**test:**

```
it('should get Erinnerungen for Auftrag from Backend', () => {
component.updateGridSubject.next(true);

expect(erinnerungService.getErinnerungenForAuftrag).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.erinnerungen.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

pipe() gets not triggert after observable was called. Don't understand why. In the running application this works.

Comment: Observables are async. Make an async test using `fakeAsync` or `waitForAsync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first take a look at what `combineLatest` does:

*The CombineLatest operator behaves in a similar way to Zip, but while Zip emits items only when each of the zipped source Observables have emitted a previously unzipped item, CombineLatest emits an item whenever any of the source Observables emits an item (so long as each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item). When any of the source Observables emits an item, CombineLatest combines the most recently emitted items from each of the other source Observables, using a function you provide, and emits the return value from that function.*

It means that your other `Observable` has to emit minimum once in order that `combineLatest` emits.

Also, the test will still not work. You have to use `fakeAsync` in combination with `tick` for async calls:

```
it('should get Erinnerungen for Auftrag from Backend', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.updateGridSubject.next(true);
  // emit other observable

  // maybe give some reasonable value here or leave empty
  tick();

  expect(erinnerungService.getErinnerungenForAuftrag).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.erinnerungen.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
}));
```

Comment: thanks for the explenation on combineLatest. With that I figured out, that I had created a wrong testing-environment. thats why my test did not work. I also didn't need fakeAsync or waitForAsync - methods for that. But thx for the help